# URL Query Parameters in Office Addin Manifest

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

When i add more than one url query parameters , say  'src', 'src1' to the home.html url in the addin manifest , it gives the build error -'src and src1 not defined'

```
<DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/App/Home.html?ver=5.0&src=true&src1=true" />
  </DefaultSettings>
```

How to add URL query parameters to the home.html in the addin manifest?

Comment: Please add details of the "build error". What are the steps the lead up to the error? Where do you see the error? Are you working with Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes iam working with Visual studio 2017. you can add more than one query parameters to any of the urls in the manifest. 

for eg: try adding to the default settings source url

<DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/App/Home.html?ver=5.0&src=true&src1=true" />
  </DefaultSettings> 

Then check the error list in VS


Error  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   
Error  Entity 'src' not defined.   
Error  Expecting ';'.  
Error  Entity 'src1' not defined.  
Error  Expecting ';'.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce. The error goes away if you encode the two `&` symbols with either `&amp;` or `%26`.